# How does sorting work with `$or` and `$in` queries in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, time-complexity

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142299/how-does-sorting-with-an-index-work-in-mongodb) - see that for context.

This question concerns a couple of special cases of the linked question - namely how sorting in MongoDB works when using `$in` or `$or` operators, and how to ensure use of an index for sorting vs. an in-memory sort.

**$in:**

For example, assume we have a collection where the document structure is

```
{a: XXX, b: XXX}
```

... and we have a compound index on `a` and `b` in that order and want to run the query

```
{a: {$in: [4, 6, 2, 1, 3, 10]}, b: {$gt: 1, $lt: 6}}
```

How would the sort proceed if it was on `a` or `b`? `$in` is an equality operator of sorts, but it seems to me that a sort on `b` with an index is impossible even so. A sort on `a` using an index is only possible if the `$in` value array is sorted first, I think - but I don't know if MongoDB does this.

**$or:**

Since `$or` queries, IIUC, are processed as multiple queries and can presumably use their respective indexes for sorts, do the sorted results get merged somehow or does `$or` force an in-memory sort of all the results? If the former, what is the time complexity of this process?

Comment: What is the question exactly? Are you asking how `$or` or `$in` affects "index" selection for a sort? Or are you asking something else? You do realize that it is also possible for a "query" stage to use one ( or even a couple with intersection ) index(es) and a "sort" to use a different index.

Comment: @NeilLunn - Hey Neil, the question has an answer at this point so I think the first part of your comment is moot, but in regards to the latter part, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36420196/643675) it's not actually possible to query on one index and sort on an entirely different index.

Comment: Saying *"not possible"* is not actually true, as there is a distinct difference between *"possible"* and what the query optimizer deems to be *"optimal"*. But the answer given below gives quite a reasonable explanation of the common cases that arrive.

Comment: @NeilLunn My interpretation of the linked answer is that it is not possible to query and sort on different indexes, period, and the optimizer can never do that. In particular I'm looking at the **Update on follow-up questions** section part 1: "You cannot have two separate indexes {a:1} and {b:1}, and expect the {a:1} index to be used for the equality part, and the {b:1} index to be used for the sort part. In this case, MongoDB will choose one of the two indexes."

Comment: Well whichever way you choose to look at it then either your "interpretation" or the "answer" are not completely correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is based on MongoDB 3.2.4.

It is worthwhile to discover the use of [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/) in MongoDB. The [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/) output of a query (e.g. `db.collection.explain().find(...)`) allows you to check which index is used in a query, and using [`db.collection.explain('executionStats')`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#executionstats-mode) will also show you whether the query succeeds or fails due to in-memory `SORT` limitation.

**$in**

A `$in` query can be thought of as a series of equality queries. For example, `{a: {$in: [1,3,5]}}` could be thought of as `{a:1}, {a:3}, {a:5}`. MongoDB will sort the `$in` array before proceeding with the query, so that `{$in: [3,5,1]}` is no different to `{$in: [1,3,5]}`.

Let's assume the collection has an index of

```
{a:1, b:1}
```

- **Sorting by `a`**

  ```
    db.coll.find({a: {$in: [1,3,5]}}).sort({a:1})
  ```

  MongoDB will be able to use the `{a:1,b:1}` index, since this query can be thought of as a union of `{a:1}, {a:3}, {a:5}` queries. Sorting by `{a:1}` allows the use of [index prefix](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-index-prefix), so MongoDB does not need to perform an in-memory sort.

  The same situation also applies to the query:

  ```
    db.coll.find({a: {$in: [1,3,5]} ,b:{$gte:1, $lt:2}}).sort({a:1})
  ```

  since `sort({a:1})` also uses the index prefix (`a` in this case), an in-memory `SORT` stage is therefore not required.
- **Sorting by `b`**

  This is a more interesting case compared to sorting by `a`. For example:

  ```
    db.coll.find({a: {$in: [1,3,5]}}).sort({b:1})
  ```

  The `explain()` output of this query will have a stage called `SORT_MERGE`. Remember that the `find()` portion of the query can be thought of as `{a:1}, {a:3}, {a:5}`.

  The query `db.coll.find({a:1}).sort({b:1})` does not need to have an in-memory `SORT` stage due to the nature of the `{a:1,b:1}` index: that is, MongoDB can simply walk the (sorted) index and return documents sorted by `b` after satisfying the equality parameter on `a`. E.g., for each `a`, there are many `b` which are already sorted by `b` due to the index.

  Using `$in`, the overall query can be thought of as:

  - `db.coll.find({a:1}).sort({b:1})`
  - `db.coll.find({a:3}).sort({b:1})`
  - `db.coll.find({a:5}).sort({b:1})`
  - Take the individual query results above, and perform a merge using the value of `b`. The query *does not need an in-memory sort stage* because the individual query results are already sorted by `b`. MongoDB just need to merge the (already sorted) sub-query results into a single result.

  Similarly, the query

  ```
    db.coll.find({a: {$in: [1,3,5]} ,b:{$gte:1, $lt:2}}).sort({b:1})
  ```

  also uses a `SORT_MERGE` stage and is very similar to the query above. The difference is that the individual queries output documents based on *a range of* `b` (instead of *every* `b`) for each `a` (which will be sorted by `b` due to the index `{a:1,b:1}`). Hence, the query does not need an in-memory sort stage.

**$or**

For an `$or` query to use an index, [every clause in the `$or` expression must have an index associated with it](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes). If this requirement is satisfied, it is possible for the query to employ a `SORT_MERGE` stage just like an `$in` query. For example:

```
db.coll.explain().find({$or:[{a:1},{a:3},{a:5}]}).sort({b:1})
```

will have an almost identical query plan, index use, and `SORT_MERGE` stage as in the `$in` example above. Essentially, the query can be thought as:

- `db.coll.find({a:1}).sort({b:1})`
- `db.coll.find({a:3}).sort({b:1})`
- `db.coll.find({a:5}).sort({b:1})`
- Take the individual query results above, and perform a merge using the value of `b`.

just like the `$in` example before.

However, this query:

```
db.coll.explain().find({$or:[{a:1},{b:1}]}).sort({b:1})
```

*cannot use any index* (since we do not have the `{b:1}` index). This query will result in a collection scan, and consequently *will have an in-memory sort stage* since no index is used.

If, however, we create the index `{b:1}`, the query will proceed like:

- `db.coll.find({a:1}).sort({b:1})`
- `db.coll.find({b:1}).sort({b:1})`
- Take the individual query results above, and perform a merge using the value of `b` (which is already sorted at both sub-queries, due to the indexes `{a:1,b:1}` and `{b:1}`).

and MongoDB will combine the results of `{a:1}` and `{b:1}` queries and perform a merge on the results. The merging process is linear time, e.g. `O(n)`.

In conclusion, in a `$or` query, every term must have an index, including the `sort()` stage. Otherwise, MongoDB will will have to perform an in-memory sort.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. And thanks for the previous answer as well, much appreciated.

Comment: Hey Kevin. I found that in the case `db.col.find({a: {$in: [val1, va2]}}).sort({b: 1})`, if I (hugely) increase the number or possibilities inside the `$in` for `a`, Mongo doesn't perform a `SORT_MERGE` but fallbacks to a rough in-memory `SORT`. This is detailled here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318304/mongo-in-with-order-indexing any advice on it ?

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON I have commented in your question.