# How to create index to process $in queries sorted by another field?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

Is there any way to create index to process queries like

```
db.col.find({a: {$in: [1, 2, 3]}).sort({b: 1})
```

or

```
db.col.find({a: {$in: [1, 2, 3]}).sort({b: 1}).limit(N)
```

effectively?

It's said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36566522/3894853) that index `{a: 1, b: 1}` should be used with `SORT_MERGE` for such queries but it doesn't, `explain()` gives me regular `SORT` only. This index is used only if I have query like `db.col.find({a: 1}).sort({b: 1})` or `db.col.find({a: {$in: [1]}).sort({b: 1})` (with only one $in element).

`hint({a:1, b:1})` also did not help.

**Upd.** Mongodb 3.2.1

Comment: I think it is not possible because of how the indices work in MongoDB. It depends on the order of keys (i.e., you cant use your index to sort by b, if you do not filter by a), therefore the values of "b" and saved in the context of values "a" and it is saved "in order", to be able to filter by a and then sort (or filter) by b... If you select "random" a's documents, it cant know, how to sort them by that index.

Comment: it can take sorted list of "b" for every "a". Then it won't need to sort them, it can merge those sorted lists much more effectively. That's exactly how `SORT_MERGE` stage works, but it does not appear in my `explain()`