# Mongo $in with order indexing

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, in-operator

I have a collection following this "schema" :

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  order: Number,
  fieldA: ObjectId,
  fieldB: Array[ObjectId]
}
```

And an index defined like this :

```
{
  fieldA: 1,
  fieldB: 1,
  order: 1
}
```

When running a find query like this one :

```
{
  $and: [
    {fieldA: {$in: [{"$oid":"592edae196232608d00f78f5"},{"$oid":"592edadc96232608d00f5614"}]}},
    {fieldB: {$in:[{"$oid":"592edace96232608d00ef77f"},{"$oid":"592edacd96232608d00ef34b"}]}}
  ]
}
```

with `sort` defined as

```
{
  order: 1
}
```

The query runs fine, the index **covers the query**, and the explain plan shows me :

- 4 IXSCANs
- 1 SORT_MERGE
- 1 FETCH

---

Issue: If I query `fieldA` and/or `fieldB` with a **huge** `$in` (I'm trying to make something like a join), then the indexing does not act the same, the query is **not covered**, the sort is made **in memory** and the explain plan shows me :

- 1 IXSCAN
- 1 FETCH
- 1 SORT_KEY_GENERATOR
- 1 SORT

Even worse, if I run this query from Mongoose, the sort operation goes out of memory :/

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). *"I'm having problems with indexing"* questions really need to be presented in a reproducible form. That means showing a case where people can work with a generated dataset with reliable results, and basically see exatcly how you are doing things, Without that, such questions always break down into a long protracted discussion about showing the explain output and theorizing this or that, and generally going nowhere.

Comment: On the other hand, If you show a reproducible case you can actually be answered as to what to do differently.

Comment: Hello Neil and thanks for your answer. I extracted the purpose from my actual use-case, made a minimal example, and extrapolated on how to reproduce the case. This would be vvery difficult, to provide a true failing dataset, since the issue is only happening with a huge one.

Furthermore, this question is more like adressed to someone who knows and read the indexing mongo core code, more to someone who's able to reproduce the issue

Comment: And, the other hand is precisely what I'm trying to avoid. I'm asking a question "why is mongo choosing this or this indexing strategy to complete that query, in that context", not "how to do things / organize my database differently to take advantage of mongodb indexing system"

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON please post your MongoDB version and the output of `db.collection.explain('executionStats').find(...)`. I suspect the plan selector determined (wrongly) that the second plan is better. You can try to use `hint()` to force it to use a certain index, so we can compare the output of `db.collection.explain('executionStats').find(...).hint(...)` with the one without the `hint()`.