# Created indexes on a mongodb collection, still fails while sorting a large data set

Tags: mongodb

My Query below:

```
db.chats.find({ bid: 'someID' }).sort({start_time: 1}).limit(10).skip(82560).pretty()
```

I have indexes on chats collection on the fields in this order

```
{
  "cid" : 1,
  "bid" : 1,
  "start_time" : 1
}
```

I am trying to perform sort, but when I write a query and check the result of explain(), I still get the winningPlan as

```
{  
   "stage":"SKIP",
   "skipAmount":82560,
   "inputStage":{  
      "stage":"SORT",
      "sortPattern":{  
         "start_time":1
      },
      "limitAmount":82570,
      "inputStage":{  
         "stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
         "inputStage":{  
            "stage":"COLLSCAN",
            "filter":{  
               "ID":{  
                  "$eq":"someID"
               }
            },
            "direction":"forward"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I was expecting not to have a sort stage in the winning plan as I have indexes created for that collection. 
Having no indexes will result into the following error

```
MongoError: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM [duplicate]
```

However I managed to make the sort work by increasing the size allocation on ram from 32mb to 64mb, looking for help in adding indexes properly

Comment: What do documents in the collection look like? What indexes do you have? What is the query?

Comment: @AndriySimonov , I have updated the question, kindly have a look again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of fields in an index matters. To sort query results by a field that is not at the start of the index key pattern the query must include equality conditions on all the prefix keys that precede the sort keys. The *cid* field is not in the query nor used for sorting, so you must leave it out. Then you put the *bid* field first in the index definition as you use it in the equality condition. The *start_time* goes after that to be used in sorting. Finally, the index must look like this:

```
{"bid" : 1, "start_time" : 1}
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index) for further reference.

Comment: thank you @andriy, I will have try the way you suggested.But can I have indexing on cid at the end, because I may use cid in other queries. May be like this {"bid" : 1, "start_time" : 1, "cid": 1}

Comment: @AnoopGoudar You probably can, however whether this index is going to be used or not depends greatly on those other queries.