# MongoDB - How Index prefixe works?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have read this documentation : "[Sort and Non-prefix Subset of an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index)"

With that info. I am trying to answer this MongoDB mock test question, the question they have is

You have the following indexes on the things collection:

```
    [
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.things"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "a" : 1
        },
        "name" : "a_1",
        "ns" : "test.things"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "c" : 1,
            "b" : 1,
            "a" : 1
        },
        "name" : "c_1_b_1_a_1",
        "ns" : "test.things"
    }
]
```

**Question:**
Which of the following queries will require that you load every document into RAM in order to fulfill the query? Assume that no data is being written during the query. Check all that apply.

```
db.things.find( { b : 1 } ).sort( { c : 1, a : 1 } )

db.things.find( { c : 1 } ).sort( { a : 1, b : 1 } )

db.things.find( { a : 1 } ).sort( { b : 1, c : 1 } )
```

The answer they give is...

```py
db.things.find( { b: 1} ).sort( {c: 1, a: 1} )
```

Can someone help me understand why the other 2 option are not correct i.e how are they using index/Index-prefix. My understanding is the SORT part has to match indexed-column-order. Also, the suggested correct answer does not seem to meet the rule (per documentation) either.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142299/how-does-sorting-with-an-index-work-in-mongodb/36420196#36420196 and let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, given the options and answer, the emphasis is to find:

> Which of the following queries will require that you load **every** document into RAM in order to fulfill the **query**?

So the sorting is a red-herring.

- `find({ b: 1 })` can't use any of the indexes provided
- `find({ c: 1 })` can use index `c_1_b_1_a_1` since it matches the prefix
- `find({ a: 1 })` can use index `a_1`

Since options #2 and #3 can use an index, they will not load *every* document in order to sort them, just the ones found via the index. Option #1 will have to do a full collection scan to find documents where `b` is `1`.