# why mongodb speed of sort by subdocument field so slow?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

my test collection has these fields

```
{
    "block_number": 123123,
    "value": 555.55555
    "transfers": [
        {
            "from": "foo1", 
            "to": "bar1", 
            "amount": 111.111
        },
        {
            "from": "foo2", 
            "to": "bar2", 
            "amount": 222.222
        },
        ...
        {
            "from": "foo3", 
            "to": "bar3", 
            "amount": 100.100
        },
    ]
},
...
{
    ...
}
```

and I made indexes like this (at python code)

```py
tx_collection.create_index("block_number")
tx_collection.create_index("transfers.amount")
tx_collection.create_index("value")
```

## Why two similar queries show different speed?

two queries are

1. `tx_collection.find({'block_number': {'$gte': 3243145}}, {'_id': 0}).sort('transfers.amount', -1).limit(100)`
2. `tx_collection.find({'block_number': {'$gte': 3243145}}, {'_id': 0}).sort('value', -1).limit(100)`

And execution time test python code is like this

```
    start = time.time()

    txs = tx_collection.find({'block_number': {'$gte': 3243145}}, {'_id': 0}).sort('transfers.amount', -1).limit(100)
    # txs = tx_collection.find({'block_number': {'$gte': 3243145}}, {'_id': 0}).sort('value', -1).limit(100)

    for tx in txs:
        print(tx)

    done = time.time()
    print(done - start)
```

### execution time

- 1st query : about 0.1 sec
- 2nd query : about 10 sec

### Why are they too different?

JFYI. the mongdb has 5 sharded and I run this query onto mongos using python code.

---

### Additional test.

When I test below query on mongodb client,

```
db.getCollection('transaction').find({}).sort({"transfers.amount":1})
```

it throws error message like

```
"Executor error during find command: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
```

#### It seems like index on `transfers.amount` seems like not working

When I checked with `db.getCollection('transaction').getIndexes()`, I confirmed that index on `transfers.amount` itself has been set well, like

```
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "transfers.amount" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "transfers.amount_1",
        "ns" : "crossangle.transaction"
    }
```

Comment: Would you send add the output of your query with ```explain```?
So that one can monitor the winning plan in your query.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142299/how-does-sorting-with-an-index-work-in-mongodb/36420196#36420196

Comment: @VijayRajpurohit Thank you for your comment. But it seems that my point is related with `transfers.amount`.

Comment: @kevinadi Thank you for your comment. I fully read. But my case is that the index on "transfers.amount" seems like not work.

Comment: @dingyo777 it's because you have `sort`. MongoDB will prefer an index that can help with sorting, and ignore all the other indexes, since typically only one index is used per query. There is a 32MB limit on `sort` memory usage. To cater for both `find` and `sort`, you need a compound index as detailed in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142299/how-does-sorting-with-an-index-work-in-mongodb/36420196#36420196. Why one query took longer than the other, more info like the `explain()` output of the query is required.

Comment: @dingyo777 the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142299/how-does-sorting-with-an-index-work-in-mongodb/36420196#36420196 actually touches on this optimization and reasons, but I understand why it's not immediately obvious. What you're seeing is the fault condition on not using a compound index.

Comment: @kevinadi Thank you for your response. Actually, I already read the link you shared. But my case which use multi key index is not explained well on the link. When I tested with `db.getCollection('transaction').find({}).sort({"transfers.amount":1})`, it reaches max memory limit. It means that sort by subfield doesn't use multi key index.

Comment: @dingyo777 yes, `transfers` and `transfers.amount` are two very different indexes, multikey or not. `transfers` indexes the subdocuments as a whole, and `transfers.amount` only indexes the number.

Comment: @kevinadi Thank you for your response. So, in mongodb, it seems that it is impossible to sort document by subdocument's subfield index.

Comment: @dingyo777 it is possible, but for the sort to not be limited to 32MB, you'll need an index for it. A relevant question is, given a document containing an array of values, how would you expect the sort result to be? But this is veering off to a different topic altogether, where a new question will be better. With the original question about speed of query, you'll need to post the `explain()` output of both queries.

Comment: @kevinadi Thank you for your response. Hmm, there is already index for the subdocument field like `transfers.amount`. 
And I totally agree with you that I will create new question.

Comment: @kevinadi I created new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314180/mongodb-multikey-index-seems-like-not-being-used-when-sort