# Sort in multiple fields aggregate

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregate, pymongo

I have a problem in sorting by multiple fields .
My query is this:

```
mydb1.mongodbbucketright.aggregate([

    {
        "$match": {
            "first": {"$gte": datetime.strptime("2010-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                          "$lte" :datetime.strptime("2020-12-31 00:55:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$samples" },


{
        "$group": {
            "_id":{
                "date": {"$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d ", "date": "$first" }},
                 "id13":"$samples.id13"
        },
      "avg_id9": {
                "$avg": "$samples.id9"
      }
      }
},
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "day":"$_id.date",
             "avg_id9":1,
            "id1313":"$_id.id13"

        }
    },
    {"$sort": {"day": -1,"id1313":1}}

])
```

When i sort only with  `day` everything works fine,but when i add the second field to `sort` the output gives me this message `Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting.`
What should i do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using [`allowDiskUse`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)?

Comment: @J.F. No i haven't because i think i have might done something wrong in project stage or group stage.I dont think allowDiskUse will help me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142299/how-does-sorting-with-an-index-work-in-mongodb

Comment: @joe I opened by mistake another url.Yes i am checking this now!

Comment: @joe I use aggregate pipeline .so the index here is a bit different i think.

Comment: yes, that's true.  If you can't rework the query to use the index to sort early on, you will need to use the `allowDiskUse` option, or further filter the stream so the total document size is less than 100MB before the sort.

Comment: @Joe Yes i understand.This is true if match filter goes from 2015-2020 works fine.2014 is the point where it exceeds the memory

Comment: @Joe Do you know how to rework my query so sort is before project?Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not really, reworking would require some schema changes.  That query looks like you are aggregating documents from 11 years 55 minutes to calculate daily averages.  Perhaps running that in smaller batches would help? or pre-calculating some of the days would reduce the data size enough to sort in memory.